# What happens under the hood to prevent calling a bound method changing the this object?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var o1 = { name: 'o1' };

var o2 = {
  name: 'o2',
  foo: function() { console.log(this.name); }.bind(o1)
}

o2.foo(); // o1 because of the 'bind'

o2.foo.call(o2); // o1 - why?
```

Is this a specific feature of bound methods that the this object on their context can never be overridden by call or apply?

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Description): The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), **which cannot be overridden**.

Comment: OK, make this the answer and I'll accept. Thanks. What is the mechanism by which the value of `this` is protected?

Comment: Done. I've also added the relevant part of the specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Description)

> The `bind()` function creates a new function (a bound function) with the
>   same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as
>   the function it is being called on (the bound function's target
>   function) with the this value bound to the first argument of `bind()`,
>   **which cannot be overridden**

---

And the technical version from the ECMA Specifiation v5.1 - defined in sections [15.3.4.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) + [15.3.4.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5.1):

### 15.3.4.5 Function.prototype.bind (thisArg [, arg1 [, arg2, …]])

> The `bind` method takes one or more arguments, `thisArg` and (optionally)
>   `arg1, arg2, etc`, and returns a new function object by performing the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. Let Target be the `this` value.
> 2. If `IsCallable(Target)` is false, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 3. Let A be a new (possibly empty) internal list of all of the argument
>      values provided after `thisArg` (`arg1, arg2 etc`), in order.
> 4. Let `F` be a new native ECMAScript object.
> 5. Set all the internal methods, except for `[[Get]]`, of `F` as specified
>      in 8.12.
> 6. Set the `[[Get]]` internal property of `F` as specified in 15.3.5.4.
> 7. Set the `[[TargetFunction]]` internal property of `F` to Target.
> 8. **Set the `[[BoundThis]]` internal property of `F` to the value of
>      `thisArg`**.
>      ...

### 15.3.4.5.1 [[Call]]

> When the `[[Call]]` internal method of a function object, F, which was
>   created using the `bind` function is called with a this value and a list
>   of arguments ExtraArgs, the following steps are taken:
>
> Let boundArgs be the value of F’s `[[BoundArgs]]` internal property. **Let
>   boundThis be the value of F’s `[[BoundThis]]` internal property**. Let
>   target be the value of F’s `[[TargetFunction]]` internal property. Let
>   args be a new list containing the same values as the list boundArgs in
>   the same order followed by the same values as the list ExtraArgs in
>   the same order. **Return the result of calling the `[[Call]]` internal
>   method of target providing boundThis as the this value and providing
>   args as the arguments**.

Answer (score 1):

It is protected by closure, You can achieve the same thing like this

```
Function.prototype.bind = function( obj ) {
  var orig_function = this;

  return function() {
    return orig_function.apply(obj, arguments);
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

#### Understanding `Function.prototype.apply`

Using `apply` or `call` you can call a function with a specific context, See the following example:

```
name = 'window';
obj = {name: 'obj'}
fn = function() {
    return this.name;
}
fn() // => 'window'
fn.apply(obj) // => 'obj'
fn.call(obj) // => 'obj'
```

The code at beginning returns a new function which binds the context using `apply` to the passed object.  Hope this helps